# Use Sql connection in a separate file in Azure Function

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, azure, azure-functions

I am using Azure function to connect to Sql database and retrieve values. I am able to install the necessary Nuget packages and perform Sql connection and querying in the Run() function

I wish to keep this database access function alone in a separate file, and return value to the main function(Run() in this case). But when i create a new class in the Azure function project and write SQL connection code, no "using" statements can be used or installed packages can be used.

I am new to Azure functions and may be i am wrong in this approach. Can you help me out? Thanks.

[image].

Comment: Yes its MS SQL Server

Comment: you need to add the needed using statements. Quick FIx sould help out.
Also, you are missing a method definition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to wrap your code in a method. Here's a sample:

```
public class SqlQuery
{
    private string cs = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("SqlConnectionString");
    
    public void Query()
    {
        using(var conn = new SqlConnection(cs))
        {
            conn.Open();
            var cmd = conn.CreateCommand("SELECT * FROM Table");
            var dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

            if(dr == null) return;
                        
            while(dr.Read())
            {

            }
        }
    }
    
}
```

Comment: you're welcome, don't forget to change the return type from void to the object you want and also include the return statement after the while.

Answer (score 1):

the screenshot you shared contains a class and has started implementation inside the class, whereas you should be creating at least one method inside your class and then add your code into the method which returns the data you expect.
try that it should work!

```
public class SqlQuery{
public void ExecuteReader()
{
    private string cs =Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("SqlConnectionString");
    using(var conn = new SqlConnection(cs))
    {
          conn.Open();
          var cmd = conn.CreateCommand("SELECT * FROM Table");
          var dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
          if(dr == null) return;
          while(dr.Read())
          {

         }
    }
}}
```

Comment: Yea i missed that out in a hurry writing! Thanks.